# Send array keys and values to csv using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv

So I am needing all my array keys to be the first column(Column 0) in an excel spreadsheet and the values of the array will be used to fill in the rest of the columns of the csv file (Columns 1-5).

See below examples

Code:

```
        $array = array();

        foreach($k["Time)"] as $key => $value)
        {
            $array[] = [$value];                  
        }

        print_r($array);


        $file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'w');




        fputcsv($file, array('Column 0','Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));


        $data = array_values($array);

        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
          fputcsv($file, $row);
        }

        fclose($file);
```

I have also tried the below and receive this error, "Array to string conversion":

```
        foreach($k["Time Series (1min)"] as $key => $value)
        {
            $array[] = [$key, $value];
        }


        var_dump($array);


        $file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'w');




        fputcsv($file, array('Column 0','Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));


        $data = $array;


        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
          fputcsv($file, $row);
        }

        fclose($file);
```

Comment: so what is not working exactly?

Comment: only printing the array values to csv, I cannot get it to print the array keys to Column 0 along with the array values to Columns 1-5

Comment: can you show the output of `var_dump($array)`? it will help immensely in finding where the issue is.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2017-08-25 16:00:00 [1] => Array ( [1. open] => 141.9550 [2. high] => 141.9800 [3. low] => 141.9200 [4. close] => 141.9700 [5. volume] => 978667 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2017-08-25 15:59:00 [1] => Array ( [1. open] => 142.0200 [2. high] => 142.0300 [3. low] => 141.9500 [4. close] => 141.9575 [5. volume] => 369713 ) )

Comment: I don't know if you already saw my answer, but I updated with your array. Hope that's what you wanted. I tested it on my end and it works.

Comment: ok thanks will test now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting the right elements

so we're working with a three dimensional array here, and not a two dimensional, which I think is where your confusion comes from.

```
// output of var_dump($array)
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [0] => 2017-08-25 16:00:00   // Column 0
    [1] => Array ( 
        [1. open] => 141.9550    // Column 1
        [2. high] => 141.9800    // Column 2
        [3. low] => 141.9200     // Column 3
        [4. close] => 141.9700   // Column 4
        [5. volume] => 978667    // Column 5
    ) 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [0] => 2017-08-25 15:59:00 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [1. open] => 142.0200 
        [2. high] => 142.0300 
        [3. low] => 141.9500 
        [4. close] => 141.9575 
        [5. volume] => 369713 
    ) 
)
```

Fix this issue, you'll need to modify the last loop like so:

```
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $rowData = array_merge(array($row[0]), $row[1]); // this will flatten your array to one dimension
    fputcsv($file, $rowData);
}
```

Comment: Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test2.php on line 49

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test2.php on line 50

Comment: My bad, I had spotted this on my editor but forgot to put it in the answer. I edited in the fix

Comment: @user7104290 no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally when I create CSV files I have only one array:

```
$array = array(
    array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3' ),
    array( 'a' => '4', 'b' => '5', 'c' => '6' ),
    array( 'a' => '7', 'b' => '8', 'c' => '9' ),
);

$file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'wb');

fputcsv( $file, array_keys( $array[0] ) );

foreach( $array as $row )
{
    fputcsv( $file, array_values( $row ) );
}

fclose( $file );
```

But if you have a separate array for a header row and values:

```
$header = array(
    'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
);

$values = array(
    array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3' ),
    array( 'a' => '4', 'b' => '5', 'c' => '6' ),
    array( 'a' => '7', 'b' => '8', 'c' => '9' ),
);

$file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'wb');

fputcsv( $file, $header );

foreach( $values as $row )
{
    fputcsv( $file, array_values( $row ) );
}

fclose( $file );
```

This is of course simplified by using simple arrays, but you should easily be able to pass in your data.

Finally, in your case:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        '2017-08-25 16:00:00',
        array(
            '1.open' => 141.9550,
            '2.high' => 141.9800,
            '3.low' => 141.9200,
            '4.close' => 141.9700,
            '5.volume' =>978667
        )
    ),
    array(
        '2017-08-25 15:59:00',
        array(
            '1.open' => 142.0200,
            '2.high' => 142.0300,
            '3.low' => 141.9500,
            '4.close' => 141.9575,
            '5.volume' => 369713
        )
    ),
);

$file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'wb');

fputcsv( $file, array_keys( $array[0][1] ) );

foreach( $array as $row )
{
    fputcsv( $file, array_values( $row[1] ) );
}

fclose( $file );
```

You could also do something like this, which would add the date to the first column:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        '2017-08-25 16:00:00',
        array(
            '1.open' => 141.9550,
            '2.high' => 141.9800,
            '3.low' => 141.9200,
            '4.close' => 141.9700,
            '5.volume' =>978667
        )
    ),
    array(
        '2017-08-25 15:59:00',
        array(
            '1.open' => 142.0200,
            '2.high' => 142.0300,
            '3.low' => 141.9500,
            '4.close' => 141.9575,
            '5.volume' => 369713
        )
    ),
);

$file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'wb');

$header_row = array_merge( array('Date' => NULL), $array[0][1] );

fputcsv( $file, array_keys( $header_row ) );

foreach( $array as $row )
{
    array_unshift( $row[1], $row[0] );
    fputcsv( $file, array_values( $row[1] ) );
}

fclose( $file );
```